# listen vs listen to

Tags: ellipsis

This sentence is from this video below.
at 2:58 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XBjdH0LFnQg

He said :

> 1) I wish I'd never **listened** all those stupid videos telling me to risk it all

I think there should be 'to' between 'listened and all' :

> 2) I wish I'd never **listened to** all those stupid videos telling me to risk it all

My Questions
1. The sentence 1) is okay grammatically?
2. Why is this guy saying it without 'to'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of grammar is correct...but he does say it with "to"!  But as (I think) a native US English speaker speaking in a fairly informal way, he minimizes the "to" so it's barely audible.

The cluster of sounds in "listene**d-to-a**ll" is hard to make very distinct unless you speak very slowly and clearly: the **d** and **t** sounds of "listened" and "to" run together unless you put a very clear stop between them, and so do the **uh** and **ah** sounds of "to" and "all".  So when a native speaker is speaking informally, it often comes out sounding like "lissendall" or "lissenall", which is what you hear in the video.  If you listen very closely, there is a very slight "stop" in his speech, like "listened'a all those..."

Comment: It might be worth noting that these captions miss more than that.  It's transcribed as "If that's the case, I wish I never said anything.  I wish I never listened all those stupid videos. . . ."  However, I hear "If that's the case, I wish I'd never said anything.  I wish I'd never listened to all those stupid videos . . . ."  But, yes, his "listened to all" is pronounced something like /lis'n t'all/, which is natural and unremarkable to my native speaker's ear.